# jQuery reloaded content calling functions from main page?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a page that refreshing part of the page every 10th second, and the reloaded content is using php to do a check in mysql database. If some cafeterias are met the refreshing should stop until a new button is pushed / function is called from the new content. My idea was letting the refresh function be controlled by javascript boolean but I cant get it to work.

In the main page I have the refresh function

```
var update = true;
function autoRefresh_div()
{
    if (update)
    {
        $("#messagebox").load("include/messagebox.php");
    }
    setTimeout(autoRefresh_div, 10000);
}
function messageboxClose()
{
    update = true;
    $('.messagebox').hide();
}
```

In the php file that is loaded except from connection to database I have a link that calls function to hide this div and also enable refreshing again.

```
<a href="#" onClick="messageboxClose(); return: false;">Hide</a>
```

And also a script that disabling refreshing

```
var update = false;
```

The problem I have is that calling the function in the main page isn't working. When refreshing update variable is set to false and refreshing content stops. But when I click the link it doesn't start again. It seems like the sub page cant access the function on the main page. Is there a better solution to this?

Comment: You could use clearTimeout instead

Comment: Error in console? BTW, it sounds like you want to recall `autoRefresh_div()` method *<<But when I click the link it doesn't start again>>*, but nothing in your posted code recall it from `messageboxClose()`. Maybe you want to use an interval instead, not a timeout. But hard to say because i don't really understand your expected behaviour

Comment: Concept should work. Could be a scope issue. Show more code

Comment: I meant: `setInterval(autoRefresh_div, 10000);` call from outside `autoRefresh_div()` method

Comment: When checking the console i found that one error was "return : false", there shouldn't be any : there. So now the hiding works but not start the refreshing. Maybe clear timeout combined with calling the refresh function is better solution then?

Comment: @Kristofer Ya you could just call `setTimeout(autoRefresh_div, 10000);` from `messageboxClose()`